# Local image filepath different in mediafile when using cordove captureimage to device file name

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have had this issue start to appear with the device file name being created in this format:

`.../DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170819_155509.jpg`

But the media file data when using Cordova captureImage being returned as:

`.../DCIM/Camera/1503140105277.jpg`

Therefore being unable to return the image.

Here is the code:

```
$('body').off('click', '#add-image-inspect-attr-list').on('click', '#add-image-inspect-attr-list', function(event) {                
            var options = { limit: 1 };
            navigator.device.capture.captureImage(inspectAttrPictureSuccess, inspectPictureError, options);
            $(this).off();
        });

function inspectAttrPictureSuccess(imageData) {

console.log(imageData);
var countOfImg = $('.image-display-inspect-attr-list').children().length;
var file = {
    ContentType: "image/jpeg",
    base64: imageData,
    Data: imageData,
    ID: countOfImg
};

var fileName = file.base64;
inspectShowAttrFile(fileName,0);
}

function inspectShowAttrFile(fileName, type) {

var countOfImg = $('.image-display-inspect-list').children().length;
$('.image-display-inspect-list').append('<img id="inspect-img-index-' + countOfImg + '" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail img-inspect" src="' + fileName[0].fullPath + '">');
}
```

The app is built with cordova 6.3.1 and the device has andriod 4.4.2

This works on some devices but not others

Comment: Missing broken code

Answer (score 0):

To get around this issue, I had to check what the last file added was to the image file location. Get the folder path, get the latest file added, then update the image data created by the captureImage function with the new file name and location data:

```
function inspectAttrPictureSuccess(imageData) {


var deviceImageFolder = imageData[0].localURL.replace(imageData[0].name, '');

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(deviceImageFolder, function (dirEntry) {
    var directoryReader = dirEntry.createReader();
    directoryReader.readEntries(successfile, failfile);
}, function (err) {
    var errToSave = err.message;
});

function successfile(entries) {
    var latestimage = entries[entries.length - 1];

    imageData[0].fullPath = latestimage.fullPath
    imageData[0].localURL = latestimage.nativeURL
    imageData[0].name = latestimage.name

    var countOfImg = $('.image-display-inspect-attr-list').children().length;
    var file = {
        Filename: "inspect-attr-img-" + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + ".jpg",
        ContentType: "image/jpeg",
        base64: imageData,
        Data: imageData,
        ID: countOfImg
    };

    inspectImageAttrFileSendAry.push(file);
    inspectImageFileSendALLAry.push(file);
    console.log(inspectImageAttrFileSendAry);
    console.log(inspectImageFileSendALLAry);
    var fileName = file.base64;
    inspectShowAttrFile(fileName, 0);

}
function failfile(error) {
    console.log("Failed to list directory contents: ", error);
}
```

}